# Complicated, nested json - how to best flatten using python

Tags: python, json, pandas, flatten, json-normalize

I have spent hours on stackoverflow, geeksforgeeks, etc. trying to find the best solution for my problem but am not landing on my desired outcome. I have a nested json that I am trying to flatten but I haven't had great luck with json_normalize(), flatten_json, etc.

Here's an example of one of my json values:

```
[{'id': '7064574404', 'type': 'INDIVIDUAL', 'name': {'first': 'John', 'middle': 'A.', 'last': 'Doe'}, 'addresses': [{'address': '774 Pony Ct', 'city': 'Aberdeen', 'state': 'IA', 'zip': '77445', 'phone': '8007777777'}, {'address': '776 S Adams St', 'city': 'Gray Mane', 'state': 'CA', 'zip': '22074', 'phone': '8882384677'}, {'address': '745 E Stallion Ave', 'city': 'White Mane', 'state': 'CA', 'zip': '22074', 'phone': '2234846627'}, {'address': '745 E Stallion Ave', 'city': 'White Mane', 'state': 'CA', 'zip': '22074', 'phone': '2234846627'}, {'address': '757 W Saint George Ave', 'city': 'Mustang', 'state': 'CA', 'zip': '22840', 'phone': '2234645662'}, {'address': '757 W Saint George Ave', 'city': 'Mustang', 'state': 'CA', 'zip': '22840', 'phone': '2234645662'}], 'specialty': ['Internal Medicine'], 'accepting': 'accepting', 'plans': [{'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740007', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740007', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740004', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740004', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740006', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740007', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740008', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740009', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740070', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740077', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740077', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740074', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740070', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740077', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740074', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740075', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740076', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740077', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740079', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077, 7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740040', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740047', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7077]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740040', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7074]}, {'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '70774CA0740047', 'network_tier': 'NETWORK', 'years': [7074]}], 'languages': ['English'], 'gender': 'Male', 'last_updated_on': 2019-07-12'}
```

Ideally, I want the name (first, middle, last), addresses (address, city, state, zip, phone), and plans (plan id type, plan id, network tier, and years) broken out into new columns. Years do NOT need to be broken out. The end goal is a readable CSV. I can do addresses and plans separately with json_normalize, but not together.

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(
    data, "addresses", ["id", "type", "specialty", "accepting", ["name", "first"], ["name", "middle"], ["name", "last"]]
)
df2

df3 = pd.json_normalize(
    data, "plans", ["id", "type", "specialty", "accepting", ["name", "first"], ["name", "middle"], ["name", "last"]]
)
df3
```

I am sure there is a simple answer that I'm just not uncovering. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have multiple `addresses` for the same row. Can you please add the expected output ?

Comment: Hi, I am hoping to have each broken out into their own columns (address1, city1, state1, zip1, phone1, address2, city2, etc.).

Comment: i believe that would be tedious to process. will it be helpful you can keep it as rows. for same `id` and `type` there will be 6 rows with different `addresses`

Comment: I was thinking the same, that makes sense. Then my question becomes how to flatten the names, addresses, and plans into one dataframe - is it doable? Do I have to use something like json_normalize for each and merge the dataframes at the end? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the data

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d)
```

use explode to split the list into columns

```
df.explode("addresses")
```

now, your input will get divided into multiple rows based on addresses column

sample:

```
id  type    addresses   specialty   accepting   plans   languages   gender  last_updated_on name.first  name.middle name.last
0   7064574404  INDIVIDUAL  {'address': '774 Pony Ct', 'city': 'Aberdeen',...   [Internal Medicine] accepting   [{'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '...   [English]   Male    2019-07-12  John    A.  Doe
0   7064574404  INDIVIDUAL  {'address': '776 S Adams St', 'city': 'Gray Ma...   [Internal Medicine] accepting   [{'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '...   [English]   Male    2019-07-12  John    A.  Doe
0   7064574404  INDIVIDUAL  {'address': '745 E Stallion Ave', 'city': 'Whi...   [Internal Medicine] accepting   [{'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '...   [English]   Male    2019-07-12  John    A.  Doe
0   7064574404  INDIVIDUAL  {'address': '745 E Stallion Ave', 'city': 'Whi...   [Internal Medicine] accepting   [{'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '...   [English]   Male    2019-07-12  John    A.  Doe
0   7064574404  INDIVIDUAL  {'address': '757 W Saint George Ave', 'city': ...   [Internal Medicine] accepting   [{'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '...   [English]   Male    2019-07-12  John    A.  Doe
0   7064574404  INDIVIDUAL  {'address': '757 W Saint George Ave', 'city': ...   [Internal Medicine] accepting   [{'plan_id_type': 'HIOS-PLAN-ID', 'plan_id': '...   [English]   Male    2019-07-12  John    A.  Doe
```

Further split by converting the dict to series

```
df.addresses.apply(pd.Series)
```

Sample output

```
address city    state   zip phone
0   774 Pony Ct Aberdeen    IA  77445   8007777777
0   776 S Adams St  Gray Mane   CA  22074   8882384677
0   745 E Stallion Ave  White Mane  CA  22074   2234846627
0   745 E Stallion Ave  White Mane  CA  22074   2234846627
0   757 W Saint George Ave  Mustang CA  22840   2234645662
0   757 W Saint George Ave  Mustang CA  22840   2234645662
```

You can continue the same approach for other columns and apply transformations based on your need.